# Posting data to my db using form in angular 5

Tags: angular, http-post, form-submit

I have some issues regarding posting/submiting data from my form to my database, here's the code, so help me if I'm using stupid approach or...

I'm working on simple crud app using asp.net mvc in my backend and angular 5 in frontend, my form is for adding new users
Currently, **my form is valid and gives me back an object in my console**, and that's fine, but can't figure out how to post it in my database...

In my service

```
  addEmployee(emp: employee) { 
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 
  'application/json');
    var body = {
        FirstName: emp.firstName, LastName: emp.lastName, Email: emp.email, 
    Password: emp.password, Role: emp.roleId
    }
      return this._http.post<employee>('organization/user', emp, { headers 
   })
      }
```

In my app.component.html

```
       <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form" #myForm="ngForm" 
     (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">


               <div class="form-group" 
     [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('firstName')">
                <label for="firstName" class="control-label required">First 
      name</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" 
   formControlName="firstName" [(ngModel)]='firstName'>

                <app-field-error-display 
    [displayError]="isFieldValid('firstName')"
                                         errorMsg="First name not valid!">
                </app-field-error-display>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('lastName')">
                <label for="lastName" class="control-label required">Last 
           name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" 
    formControlName="lastName" [(ngModel)]='lastName'>
                <app-field-error-display 
       [displayError]="isFieldValid('lastName')"
                                         errorMsg="Last name not valid!">
                </app-field-error-display>
            </div>
                .
                .
                .

      <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary" (click)="Save(myForm)" >
                Submit
            </button>
```

And in my app.component.ts

```
 employees: Observable<employee[]> 
 employeelist: employee[];
 mappedlist: employee[] = [];
 Demoemployee: employee;

    GetDemoObject(myForm: NgForm): employee
   {
    this.Demoemployee = new employee;
    this.Demoemployee.firstName = myForm.value.firstName;
    this.Demoemployee.lastName = myForm.value.lastName;
    this.Demoemployee.email = myForm.value.email;,
    this.Demoemployee.password = myForm.value.password;
    this.Demoemployee.location = myForm.value.location;
    this.Demoemployee.roleId = myForm.value.roleId; 
    return this.Demoemployee;
  }

     AddEmployee(e: employee) {
    this._usermanagementservice.addEmployee(this.Demoemployee).subscribe(res 
              => {
        this.employeelist.push(res); 
    });
     }

   Save(myForm: NgForm) {
    this.GetDemoObject(myForm).this.AddEmployee(this.Demoemployee);
    } 


   onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
        console.log("Form Submitted!", this.form.value);
        this.form.reset();
    }
  }
```

I guess Save function is the issue, how do I call my function from service into my component, getting all the values from the form and then posting it to database? :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject your service into your component :

**in service.ts**

```
addEmployee(emp: employee) { 
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var body = {
        FirstName: emp.firstName, LastName: emp.lastName, Email: emp.email, 
    Password: emp.password, Role: emp.roleId
    }
      return this._http.post<employee>('organization/user', body, { headers 
   })
      }
```

**in app.component.ts**

```
constructor(public service:Service){
}

Save(myForm: NgForm) {
    this.GetDemoObject(myForm); 
    this.AddEmployee(this.Demoemployee);
}
```

**in app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers : [Service]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I have injected it, already have another function for displaying my current users in db... let my try this Save function, I'll get back to you

Comment: this is isn't working, I already have AddEmployee function in my component, which should work? :/

Comment: ah I got confused with your syntax in the `Save` function ... why the chaining ? `this.GetDemoObject(myForm).this.AddEmployee(this.Demoemployee);` strikes me odd , I would have `this.GetDemoObject(myForm); this.AddEmployee(this.Demoemployee);`

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type", url: "http://localhost:54953/organization/user", ok: false, …}
error
:
exceptionMessage
:
"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'User' from content with media type 'text/plain'."
exceptionType
:
"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException"
message
:
"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."

Comment: Sorry I've misread, i think its a headers issue , try to add `Accept:application/json` as a header as well as `Content-Type`

Comment: Up there you can see my function in service, where I've added app/json and content type

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing the specific of your API, I would check that that the request is really sent with these headers and check if what the server accepts as format.